# Python - Running function concurrently (multiple instance)

Tags: python, concurrency, multiple-instances

I built a little function that will gather some data using a 3rd party API. Call if def `MyFunc(Symbol, Field)` that will return some info based on the symbol given.

The idea was to fill a Pandas df with the returned value using something like:

```
df['MyNewField'] = df.apply(lamba x: MyFunc(x, 'FieldName'))
```

All this works **BUT**, each query takes around **100ms** to run. This seems fast until you realize you may have 30,000 or more to do (3,000 Symbols with 10 fields each for starters).

I was wondering if there would be a way to run this concurrently as each request is independent? I am not looking for multi processor etc. libraries but instead a way to do multiple queries to the 3rd party at the same time to reduce the time taken to gather all the data. (Also, I suppose this will change the initial structure used to store all the received data - I do not mind not using Apply and my dataframe at first and instead save the data as it is received on a text or library type structure -).

NOTE: While I wish I could change MyFunc to request multiple symbols/fields at once this cannot be done for all cases (meaning some fields do not allow that and a single request is the only way to go). This is why I am looking at concurrent execution and not at changing MyFunc.

Thanks!

Comment: "a way to do multiple queries to the 3rd party at the same time to reduce the time taken to gather all the data" -- if you want to do this, you need to change `MyFunc` to handle multiple queries at a time. Otherwise, the only option is multiprocessing.

Comment: @cheersmate that is my main goal. I could pass MyFunc a list of Symbols and many Fields instead of just do a query for each. However, that involves the problem all knowing all queries you want to do in advance. Since I can do multiple queries concurrently my goal is to try to see first if Python can run multiple instances of MyFunc somehow saving the returned data. This is the main aim of my question here.

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries to parallelize pandas dataframe. However, I prefer native multi-processing pool to do the same. Also, I use tqdm along with it to know the progress.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Pool

cores = 4 #Number of CPU cores on your system
partitions = cores #Define as many partitions as you want

def partition(data, num_partitions):
    partition_len = int(len(data)/num_partitions)
    partitions = []

    num_rows = 0
    for i in range(num_partitions-1):
        partition = data.iloc[i*partition_len:i*partition_len+partition_len]
        num_rows = num_rows + partition_len
        partitions.append(partition)

    partitions.append(data.iloc[num_rows:len(data)])
    return partitions

def parallelize(data, func):
    data_split = partition(data, partitions)
    pool = Pool(cores)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

df['MyNewField'] = parallelize(df['FieldName'], MyFunc)
```

Comment: Thanks Said. Is parallel computing the solution here? I was under the impression an option would be to create multiple objects and have each one of them do a query. My understanding of parallel computing  is that it would help make that process even more efficient but I am happy for the OS to split the work (think of Excel, when you have a function on multiple cells they are all running independently and at the same time).

Comment: Here partition breaks dataframe into multiple objects.
Then based on the number of cores, processes are created. Each process picks a dataframe partition independently and performs MyFunc transformation.